# Как из полного пути файла получить расширение?

Tags: python, python-3.x, файловая-система, пути

Можно ли как-то из переменной, которая содержит путь, получить только расширение файла?

Comment: `os.path.splitext`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь встроенными в Python платформо-независимыми инструментами для работы с путями - [os.path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) или более продвинутым [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html).

**Вариант 1**:

```
import os.path as osp

filename = r"c:\path\to\file.ext"
ext = osp.splitext(filename)[1]
```

**Вариант 2**:

```
from pathlib import Path

filename = Path(r"c:\path\to\file.ext")
ext = filename.suffix
```

Пример:

```
In [226]: filename = Path(r"c:\path\to\file.aaa.bbb.ccc.txt")

In [227]: filename.suffix
Out[227]: '.txt'
```

Comment: Вариант 1 сбойнёт, если в имени каталога есть точка, а у самого файла нет расширения.  osp.splitext(r"c:\path\to\dir.1\file")[1] => ".1\file"

Comment: @Akina, подозреваю вы проверяли этот вариант на UNIX|Posix OS ? ;)

Comment: Нет (или да? не знаю), на https://replit.com/languages/python3

Comment: @Akina, `import sys; print(sys.platform)`

Comment: Да, говорит, что он "linux". Хотя формально автор не ограничивается Win-системами (с другой стороны - расширение...).

Answer (score 1):

Простой вариант

```
filename = "c:\path\to\file.ext"
extension = filename.split('.')[-1]
```